# Missing Trash mechanism in Xfce after manual RHEL installation

Tags: rhel, xfce, trash

#### Installation by steps:

1. RHEL minimal (prompt only & internet connection)
2. X Window system
3. epel-release
4. Xfce (+some plugins)

After all I can't find `Trash` folder. I guess I forgot to install something, but I can't guess the package name to enable Trash mechanism.

So the question is: **How to enable Trash folder mechanism in Xfce?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I figured out myself: its necessary to install package **gvfs** - and trash returns back.

---

So if you want to remove **trash** from **thunar Xfce** (or **caja Mate**) - you should remove that package or it's better to remove only properties file, because **gvfs** affects not only **trash**:

```
/usr/share/gvfs/mounts/trash.mount
```

[GNOME Virtual file system - **gvfs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs) - also affects on:

*admin, burn, cdda, computer, dav, dav+sd, dns-sd, ftp, ftps, http, localtest, network, recent, sftp*

So I need it in my installation process - it's not completed, I guess..